# Reading the value of Target Device Family

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is it possible to determine what value has been set for Target Device Family from the code? 
I have two project files that share the same sources and I would like to know which resources to load depending on what the project setting is. 
I could of course add a new value to the .plist files which are different for each project, but I'm trying to avoid any unnecessary settings.

Using UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM will not work as that depends on what device is used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, the *Target Device Family* is a **Project** (and/or target) setting. Once the app is compiled and bundled, it's not visible anymore.

However, if you want to provide different versions of a resource file for the iPad / iPhone, you can use `~ipad` and `~iphone` suffixes for filenames.

E.g.:

```
image~ipad.png
image~iphone.png
```